# Starting columns in the middle of itemize environment

Tags: beamer, itemize, columns, beamerposter

(How) can I start column in the middle of itemize environment? A M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Signs
  \begin{itemize}
    \item The majority of putative abstract ``signs"
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.64\textwidth}
    \item 17 distinct signs have been discovered.
    \item Egg shells, dated to 60 kya, have also been discovered.
    \end{column}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

  \begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
  pictures will go here
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces only `3: Missing $ inserted`. I need it for a poster (using package `beamerposter`)

Comment: M(N)WE ... he ... hehe. True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without interfering with the itemization flow at all using `\smash`.

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Signs
  \begin{itemize}
    \item The majority of putative abstract ``signs"
    \item 17 distinct signs have been\\ discovered. 
    \item Egg shells, dated to 60 kya,\\ have also been discovered. 
    \qquad \smash{\includegraphics[height=3.5\baselineskip]{example-image}}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. What do you need `lmodern` for?

Comment: For making all font sizes available for precise scaling without size substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

- beamer blocks need a title, even if it is empty
- if you open an environment inside another one, you also have it to close inside of it

---

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Signs
  \begin{itemize}
    \item The majority of putative abstract ``signs"
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \item 17 distinct signs have been discovered.
    \item Egg shells, dated to 60 kya, have also been discovered.
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
     pictures will go here
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

To get a homogeneous spacing, I suggest another approach:

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Signs
        \begin{itemize}
            \item The majority of putative abstract ``signs"
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \vspace*{-.8\baselineskip}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[]
              \begin{itemize}
                    \item 17 distinct signs have been discovered.
                    \item Egg shells, dated to 60 kya, have also been discovered.
            \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot done :)